# WPML dropdown widget switcher not working

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I don't know why, but my widget switcher for wpml not working. I added custom position using this code

```
<div class="topbar">
                 <?php do_action('wpml_add_language_selector'); ?>
            </div>
```

Dropdown not working for other languages.
But in wpml preview looks fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess You didn't translated your contents . in this case if you want show all languages change this :

**How to handle languages without translation
Some pages or posts may not be translated to all languages. Select how the language selector should behave in case translation is missing.**

- Link to home of language for missing translations